# Python/Lesta.A worm

Tags: virus

My Nod32 have been catching something that is apparently identified as Python/Lesta.A worm. No matter how many times I tell Nod32 to delete and quarantine the file, it always re-appear, the situation will repeat about 3-4 times a day.

This thing has been creating a folder called "pamela" in one of my drives, it sometimes also creates a "xxx.folder" file, which Nod32 identifies as "Exploit/CodeBase virus".

I have Googled, and done pretty much everything related to this: a full scan in safe mode with no networking turned on, and also ran Ad-Aware, SpyBot, SpyHunter, ComboFix and cleaned the registry.

Any idea how I can completely get rid of this annoying virus/worm?

Answer (score 0):

You can find information about [manually removing](http://www.pcthreat.com/parasitebyid-8734en.html) it.  In particular, [backup your registry](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322756) then try removing the key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\WINDOWS\CURRENTVERSION\RUN\Aleste
```

You can find many [tutorials](http://www.windowsmaven.com/How_to_use_regeditl.htm) for using the registry.

Answer (score 0):

Its probably a rootkit, try GMER to identify and remove it.

http://www.gmer.net/